# PHP - refactoring this if statement to avoid duplication

Tags: php, if-statement, code-duplication

In this snippet of code we type `$inputs['user_id']` 3 times.

```
if (isset($inputs['user_id']) && $inputs['user_id']) { // The consumer is passing a user_id
    doSomethingWith($inputs['user_id']);
}
```

What's the most readable and robust refactoring I can do to avoid the duplication and avoid any notice that the index `user_id` doesn't exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here nothing is wrong with the duplication. You cannot assign `$inputs['user_id']` to a variable before checking if it is set, otherwise this will produce a `Notice undefined index ...`.

The only thing here could be done is to omit the `isset` call and use `!empty` instead, like this:

```
if(!empty($inputs['user_id'])) {
    doSomething($inputs['user_id']);
}
```

Now You are only typing it twice and the check

```
!empty($inputs['user_id'])
```

equals to

```
isset($inputs['user_id']) && $inputs['user_id']
```

**EDIT:** based on a comments, here is a quote from [documentation](http://php.net/empty):

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

So either `empty(0)` or `empty('0')` will return `true`, that means

```
if(!empty('0') || !empty(0)) { echo "SCREW YOU!"; }
```

**will echo nothing**... Or, in polite way, I will repeat the statement above:

```
!empty($inputs['user_id']) === (isset($inputs['user_id']) && $inputs['user_id'])
```

### **EDIT 2:**

By omitting the `isset` and replacing by `!empty` the variable is **still checked, whether the index is already set**, please read the [documentation](http://php.net/empty), which says:

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means **empty()** is essentially the concise equivalent to **!isset($var) || $var == false**.

Comment: `empty('0') = true`, one should be aware of that fact.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
// put validation check to the function body
function doSomethingWith($userId) {
     if($userId === -1) {
         // if this is not a valid user id -> return
         return;
     }
     // do something ...
}

// initalize $user with proper default values.
// doing so you can be sure that the index exists
$user = array(
    'id' => -1,
    'name' => '',
    ...
);

// merge inputs with default values:
$user = array_merge($user, $request);

// now you can just pass the value:
doSomethingWith($user['id']);
```

Comment: @AmalMurali What do you mean by *refactor*?

Comment: This is similar to what I was about to suggest; if there's a "default" invalid valid that `doSomethingWith` cannot accept (I'd usually go with `null`, not `-1`; `-1` often ends up being `error` since it's the right datatype for an ID), have a guard statement at the beginning so it returns early.

Comment: @hek2mgl - You may want to add & before the argument `doSomethingWith(&$userId)` in case the variable is undefined, so the php would not complain

Comment: @i-- Can you explain that?

Comment: @hek2mgl - I am not exactly sure why passing by reference instead of value in function declaration gives no warning, I just know that it works. Curious to know myself why exactly. Guessing something to do with variable being auto assigned in such a case.

Comment: @i-- where do I pass something by reference?

Comment: @hek2mgl - are you really not following or just messing with me?

Comment: @i-- No, I really can't follow. Please prepare an example, post it to pastebin and show the link

Comment: @hek2mgl - I just posted my version of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below might not be the best way for every situation, but definitely cuts down on the repetition.

Your example code would turn into:

```
doSomethingWith($inputs['user_id']);
```

and your function would look like this *(notice the argument supplied by reference, to avoid the undefined variable warning)*:

```
function doSomethingWith(&$userID) {
   if (empty($userID)) return;
   // ... actual code here ...
}
```

Comment: passing by reference in PHP has many (sometimes unexpected) side-effects and should be handled with care. That's why I wouldn't suggest this as a general solution. However, it works in this case, +1 for the hack! But I would not use it in production code...

Comment: Thanks. Agree about the care, but it also gives the language another level of power, if one knows what he/she is doing.

Comment: This is really not bad (to solve this question) ! :) When I say *to solve this question* I mean when handling not only strings or numbers unexpected side behaviour (especially performance issues) might occur. But as you say, if handled with care it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `0` and `""` and `null` are not valid user_ids:

```
if ($id = $inputs['user_id']) { 
    doer($id);
}
```

YOu can also do with evil `@` to avoid notice in your logs, (I don't like this way):

```
if ($id = @$inputs['user_id']) { 
    doer($id);
}
```

Comment: This also assumes that the index `user_id` is always set - I assume from the `isset` in the original question that this may not be the case.

Comment: No. I assume that an empty var will not pass the check and the valid one does.